# FB.login() inside inapp browser (no popups)

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have my Facebook login process working on desktop and mobile, except for Facebook's inapp mobile browser (ios and now android). The issue is that if you call `FB.login()`, nothing at all happens. I assume this is because the inapp browser doesn't deal with popups.

I understand that a redirect auth flow circumvents the need for a login/permissions popup, however I have built a web-app, which means it is a pain to deal with storing the users current state at the point of signing in.

Does anyone have any good solutions for this?

Also I have tested many other sites login buttons through the inapp browser, and all of the ones I have tried so far don't work. Facebook has done a great job of breaking a large amount of sign up processes.

Comment: how do you call FB.login? a small code example would help.

Comment: It is called via a click event (if that was your worry), and has been tested on every other platform. This is purely to do with the inapp browser not launching popups, and is broken on many sites.

Comment: well, i assume it´s not the problem with calling FB.login in an asynchronous callback then...do you have a test site online?

Comment: Just go to any site with a facebook login whilst inside the inapp Facebook browser. FB.login() attempts to create a popup, and the inapp browser does not allow popups.

Comment: ah, now i know what you mean. that pretty new inapp browser they implemented only a few days ago? sorry, i did think about that one. good catch, i will definitely check it out.

Comment: For android yes, but ios has had the issue for a while.

Comment: `FB.getLoginStatus` does not work too. So it seems that popups are not the problem. For me it works on all devices except the ones with Android 5. I'm actually discussing this in the [Facebook developer group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/813174875392695/?comment_id=813223138721202&offset=0&total_comments=1). I will leave any news here.

Comment: This is quite old, but i still have the same problem.. is there any solution already which im missing or it is still impossible to call FB.login in the Facebook messenger In-App Browser?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, that seems to be a bug either in the Android FB- App or in the Android 5 WebView component. There is a [**bug report**](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1651116428448693/) at facebook, but they are still working on it. The only solution i could find for now is to turn off the internal browser: http://www.androidpit.com/facebook-disable-browser

Because that action has to be taken by the user itself, it's no satisfying solution. Therefore i guess the only thing we can do at the moment is to stay tuned for facebooks fix.

**Update**

Facebook confirmed this is a bug. They are working on it. Stay tuned...

**2nd Update**

Facebook rolled out a patch. Works for me now.

Comment: They say that the bug is fixed, but for me its still not working? Check this link  - open with in-app browser: http://www.nottyfly.com/manage/public/?page=promotion&type=webpoints&noredirect=1&p=559a7de99a964

Comment: @Peter Facebooks link works for me on a Nexus 9 with Android 5.1.1. Please try to post this [link](http://www.fbrell.com/Facebook%20Login/2%20-%20Checking%20and%20Tracking%20Login%20Status#) on a test fb page of yours and open it in the internal Browser. Is the login button working. Which devices are you using?

Comment: FacebookApp in-app browser works, but seems the FacebookLite didn't :-(